# ember computed property based on model properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm quite new to ember and trying to write a computed property that checks whether or not a user is online based on their 'state' property, defined in the user model, and then returns a count of the number of users online. This is what I have been attempting, which is not working-

```
onlineUsers: function() {
    return this.get("model").filterBy("state", "online").get("model.length");
}.property("'model.[]'"),
```

And this is my user model-

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name   : DS.attr('string'),
  email  : DS.attr('string'),
  state  : DS.attr('string'),
  subjects    : DS.hasMany('subject')    
});
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `model.@each.state`

```
onlineUsers: function() {
  return this.get("model").filterBy("state", "online").get("length");
}.property("model.@each.state"),
```

Also `model.length` in the end not work, because the result of the `filterBy` is a new array, and you want the length of that array.